# Looping through an observableArray using foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I have this observable array in my view model.

```
this.months = ko.observableArray(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar',...]);
```

If I try to display each month, like this -

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: months, as: 'month' } -->
<span data-bind="text: month"></span>        
<!-- /ko -->
```

It throws an error -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return month }"
Message: month is not defined
```

If I try this,

```
<!-- ko foreach: months -->
<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

it displays [object object]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're doing wrong, but this works fine. Looks like your `months` isn't what you think it is.

```js
vm = {};

vm.months = ko.observableArray(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko foreach: {data: months, as: 'month'} -->
<span data-bind="text: month"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong. I deleted everything knockout related from the page and added back one by one. And it works now.

Comment: I hate it when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
`<span data-bind="text: month"></span>`
```

expects you to provide data with property month. but yours is array of string, therefore it will throw error. knockout is looking for month observable in that array.

As Roy suggested, below should work.

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: months, as: 'month'} -->
<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Or you can change your observable array to provide observable data with month as property.

```
months = [{month:'jan'}, {month:'Feb'}, {month:'Mar'},...]);
```

make sure you provide observable array.

Comment: The `as: 'month'` allows you to use `month` instead of `$data`. I updated my example to illustrate.